# Loop to process a column of data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a column of data and move all data below "south" but above "north"/"east"/"West". The data is random and tied to each title so I can't sort alphabetically.

Without the loop; I am able to sort the first cell under "south".

```vb
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngFoundTrue As Range
 
    Set rngFound = Cells.Find(What:="SOUTH", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
 
    Set rngFoundTrue = rngFound.Offset(1, 0)
    rngFoundTrue.Cut Destination:=rngFoundTrue.Offset(0, 1)
    Set rngFound = Nothing
 
    Do Until rngFoundTrue.Value = "NORTH" Or "WEST" Or "EAST"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well there is nothing in the loop. you probably want to put the cut/paste operation in there for it to do anything. But if it's a lot of data, it's probably faster to check the row of the next title and move all at once.

Comment: This: `Do Until rngFoundTrue.Value = "NORTH" Or "WEST" Or "EAST"` does not do what you probably think it does.

Comment: You have failed to explain what needs to be done. Try adding some screenshots and add more info, among others, also related to the following: `Cells.` references all the cells in the `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell` is a random cell, `SOUTH`, `xlPart` and the first `False` will make sure that `issoUthOF` will be found. You're cutting one cell to paste to another one. A `Do...Loop` statement needs a `Do` and a `Loop`. You need to help us to help you.